# How to get unique values in column 1 based on column 2 condition

Tags: python, dataframe

[image]

Hi all, above is the dataframe that I am working on.
I am trying to get the list of unique values from the Stock column with the condition that Type.1 values is not equal to 'Sell'.

Therefore, the expected results are Genting, Epure and Mercator. Swiber will not be in the list because the record has 'Sell' value under Type.1 column.

I tried to use this code, but encountered an error. May I seek suggestions on how to fix this?

```
#Tried this but fail with error ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given
companyNames= np.where(portfolioDf["Type.1"] is not "Sell", portfolioDf.loc[:,"Stock"])

#Tried this also fail with error ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given
companyNames= np.where(portfolioDf["Type.1"] is not "Sell", portfolioDf.Stock.unique())
```

Comment: Can you share the libraries you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
to_remove = df.loc[df["Type.1"] == "Sell", "Stock"]
print(df.loc[~df["Stock"].isin(to_remove), "Stock"].unique())
```

Comment: in the same dataframe, there is a row with value "Div" under the same column (Type.1). I tried to add in a second condition but returns zero. Any idea where gone wrong? `to_remove = portfolioDf.loc[(portfolioDf["Type.1"] == "Sell") & (portfolioDf["Type.1"] == "Div") , "Stock"]`

Comment: @vitalstrike82 Try to change `&` to `|`

Comment: Oh ya. Stupid me. Why i put and condition. Guess time for me to stop. Cant think anymore. thanks Andrej

Answer (score 0):

you can try with:

```
portfolioDf['Stock'].loc[portfolioDf['Type.1']!='Sell'].unique()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
portfolioDf[portfolioDf["Type.1"] != "Sell"]["Stock"].unique()
```